# Post Merge transaction selection time

Tags: gas-price

I was wondering if anyone has some historical data on how long the delay is from broadcasting a transaction to the Ethereum network before it is being picked up by a miner after The Merge? Preferably with a high priority fee such that miners would likely pick the transaction for the upcoming blocks.

I've searched for this data a lot of places, however I can't find any concrete data outside some *guesstimates*. On [Etherscan gas tracker](https://etherscan.io/gastracker) they provide some information about gas cost and the priority associated with the price, but there is no historical data that can be used.